# Python class 'int' object not callable

Tags: python

I have googled this error already and didn't understand what it is. I am trying to make a simple game with classes and the enemy class I have won't allow me to call the attack method.

This is the line it says the error is on:

```
enemy.attack(player1)
if player1.dead == True:
    print "You have lost"
```

And this is the method:

```
def attack(self, player):
    #defend = randint(0,10)

    damage = randint(0, self.strength)
    if damage == 0:
        print "You missed"
    elif damage < self.strength:
        print "Hit for", damage,"damage."
        player.health = player.health - damage
    elif damage == self.strength:
        print "Critical hit!"
        player.health = player.health - (damage + 2) 
    player.check_dead(player)
```

If you need more information about the code please ask. I'm not sure what information I am meant to give you because I don't understand the error.

Error in the console:

```
Your health: 100
Attack or Heal attack
Hit for 3 damage.
97

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Computing\player.py", line 119, in <module>
    enemy.attack()
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: please post the full traceback (the error in the console)

Comment: Post the source with class enemy and player please..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At some point you assigned an `int` value to `enemy.attack`, then tried to call `enemy.attack()` as a function.

Look for a line like `xyz.attack = {something}` and scrutinize what `{something}` is.

---

Advanced debugging technique - make `enemy.attack` a read-only property which returns a do-nothing function, ie

```
class enemy:
    @property
    def attack(self, player):
        def null_fn():
            pass
        return null_fn
```

... now running your code will throw an `AttributeError` pointing at the line where you try to assign a value to `attack` ;-)

Comment: I had given it an instance variable called attack.